# roc_auc_score from sk-learn gives error when test label vector with classes has only a subset of the whole set

Tags: scikit-learn, class-imbalance, multiclass-classification, roc

I have an imbalanced dataset.
Does it make sense to compute the roc-auc for the classifier I created in a holdout set?

Here's very artificial MWE:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear").fit(X, y)

# Let's assume that X_test = X, y_test is just a vector of 1s. 
roc_auc_score([1]*150, clf.predict_proba(X_test), multi_class='ovr')

ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict_proba` method will return a `numpy` array of shape `(n_samples,2)` with the probability of `Y == 1` and `Y == 0` but you need to pass only the probability of `Y == 1` for `roc` calculation so:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear").fit(X, y)

# Let's assume that X_test = X, y_test is just a vector of 1s. 
roc_auc_score([1]*150, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1], multi_class='ovr')
```

Comment: Julio, thanks ;)